# DirectX 11/12 without UWP possible?

Tags: directx, directx-11, directx-12

I've haven't looked at DirectX since the DX9 era. Is it possible to make DX11/12 applications without having to also make them UWP applications?

I'm a little concerned about the overhead of UWP-- for fun, I made an empty application, and I noticed it uses ~30MB just to draw a blank window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing by "WUP" you mean the Universal Windows Platform (UWP). Direct3D 11 is supported for Win32 classic desktop apps on Windows 7, Windows Vista SP2, Windows 8.x, and Windows 10. Direct3D 12 is supported for Win32 classic desktop apps on Windows 10. Both are also supported for UWP and Xbox One.

> To catch up on the modern story for DirectX, you should see: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx), [Where is the DirectX SDK (2015 Edition)?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/08/05/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2015-edition/), and [Getting Started with Direct3D 11](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2011/07/11/getting-started-with-direct3d-11/), as well as the [DirectX Tool Kit tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) tutorials

There are three basic appmodels for UWP: XAML, XAML+DirectX, and DirectX (i.e. no XAML). A basic DirectX app for Direct3D 11 with just a swap chain and device has an EXE of about 100 KB as an x86 application in Release mode. A DirectX+XAML 'empty' app is around 347 KB.

**UPDATED**: The basic DirectX app for Direct3D 11 as Release mode for x86 has a RAM footprint of around 6.1 MB in full-screen mode. A DirectX+XAML 'empty' app in Release mode for x86 is 11.2 MB. That's pretty good since a 1920 x 1080 BGRA32 render target texture is 8 MB of VRAM.

Comment: Whoops! Typo'd that twice! Yes, I meant the Universal Platform. 30MB is the memory footprint of the program I created in Visual Studio 2015 which only had a blank window, running in release mode.

Comment: Even if the app is 30MB empty, why is it a concern ? It is not like computers run with GBs of RAM now. You are more likely to waste memory in your user code than in services overhead. Also you do not say much on your test, was it debug, release, static or dynamic linkage, 32 or 64bits, etc ! The UWP runtime is not optimized for an empty application, it is made to do a real application where 30MB are nothing, and may also  shared between all the alive UWP applications.

Comment: Not all machines run with tons of RAM. You don't know my use case. Stop being condescending.

Comment: UWP is intended to provide the same programming surface across a wide variety of devices from 64 GB+ workstations down to Internet of Things devices. It's pretty efficient in Release mode in terms of memory footprint. The only thing that tends to get 'bloaty' are the build intermediaries like ``.obj`` files and ``.pch`` files so it takes a fair amount of diskspace to build the app. The result itself is not particularly heavy-weight compared to equal functionality in a Win32 classic desktop app.